# config parser の変数参照の書き方

Tags: python

config.ini を以下のように書いて

```
[DEFAULT]
env = development

[s3]
bucket = serverlogs.%(env)
prefix = logs/
```

以下のような同じディレクトリの Python スクリプトから読み出したところ

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.ini'), encoding='utf-8')
bucket = config['s3']['bucket']
```

以下のエラーになります

```
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: bad interpolation variable reference '%(env)'
```

https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.BasicInterpolation
このドキュメントを見ながら書いてるんですが
最初のクイックスタートは `=` で書かれているのに
変数展開のところは `:` のサンプルしかなくて `=` で書く場合は変数展開ができないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`env`が他のセクションの物だからでしょう。

[class configparser.ExtendedInterpolation](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ExtendedInterpolation)を追加して、

```
import os
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config._interpolation = configparser.ExtendedInterpolation()  #### 追加

config.read(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)), 'config.ini'), encoding='utf-8')
bucket = config['s3']['bucket']
```

追加方法はこちらの1行としてパラメータ指定でも良いようです。

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=configparser.ExtendedInterpolation())
```

iniファイルの方は

```
bucket = serverlogs.${DEFAULT:env}
```

と書く必要があると思います。

> 他のセクションから値を持ってくることもできます:
>
> ```
> [Common]
> home_dir: /Users
> library_dir: /Library
> system_dir: /System
> macports_dir: /opt/local
>
> [Frameworks]
> Python: 3.2
> path: ${Common:system_dir}/Library/Frameworks/
>
> [Arthur]
> nickname: Two Sheds
> last_name: Jackson
> my_dir: ${Common:home_dir}/twosheds
> my_pictures: ${my_dir}/Pictures
> python_dir: ${Frameworks:path}/Python/Versions/${Frameworks:Python}
> ```

Comment: うまくいきました
> ConfigParser が使用するデフォルト実装です。値に、同じセクションか特別なデフォルトセクション中 1 の他の値を参照するフォーマット文字列を含めることができます
とあったのでデフォルトの方でもDEFAULT内はアクセスできると思ってました

Answer (score 2):

エラーは、「`%(env)`」だからです。「`%(env)s`」(後ろに「s」を付ける)にするとエラーがなくなります。

```
>>> import configparser
>>> parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
>>> parser.read_string('''
... [DEFAULT]
... env = development
... 
... [s3]
... bucket = serverlogs.%(env)s
... ''')
>>> parser['s3']['bucket']
'serverlogs.development'
>>>
```

Comment: そうだったんですか。私も誤解していました。